# Changing the positions of text and figures in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose that I have something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=black!40, draw = black!40, line width=2pt]
    (-2, -2.5) rectangle +(\textwidth, 4cm);
\draw (2, -0.3) node[right, text
    width=\textwidth-4.5cm] {This is a test as you can see and we put more text to see what happens here and there.};
\draw[red, fill=white, rounded corners = 5pt, line width=10pt]
    (30:2cm) -- (150:2cm) -- (270:2cm) -- cycle;
\draw (0, 0.3) node {Hello};
\draw (0, -0.3) node {Goodbye};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces something like this

[image]

I have a grayish box, a figure on the left (with red line, some text, white as filling color) and one block of text. Now if I wish to put the figure on the right hand side of that gray box so it will be exactly the same distance from right hand side of the gray box that it is now horizontally from the left hand side of the gray box, and if I wish to the same thing with the text block (put the text block on the left hand side of that gray box so it will be exactly the same distance from the left hand side of the gray box that it is now horizontally from the right hand side of the gray box), what I have to do?

Comment: Your code just make use of Cartesian coordinates. You need to change them. For example, you can insert the text node at position `(4,0)`  instead of `(2, -0.3)`. So, just figure out what coordinates you want to use.

Comment: @Sigur: That is tedious. I thought tikz is smart enough to do what I wanted.

Comment: It could be if the code was smarted produced. For example, if you give a name to a node you can insert another node using relative positions: `left of` for example.

Comment: Use `scope` to translate the sign to right:  `\begin{scope}[xshift=\textwidth-4.5cm]
\draw[red, fill=white, rounded corners = 5pt, line width=10pt]
    (30:2cm) -- (150:2cm) -- (270:2cm) -- cycle;
\draw (0, 0.3) node {Hello};
\draw (0, -0.3) node {Goodbye};
\end{scope}`. Move text to left: `\draw (-1.5, -0.3)`. Some fine tuning could be necessary.

Answer (score 5):

As Sigur suggested, you can use `scopes` to shift the sign and the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=black!40, draw = black!40, line width=2pt]
    (-2, -2.5) rectangle +(\textwidth, 4cm);
\draw (2, -0.3) node[draw, right, text
    width=\textwidth-4.5cm] {This is a test as you can see and we put more text to see what happens here and there.};
\draw[red, fill=white, rounded corners = 5pt, line width=10pt]
    (30:2cm) -- (150:2cm) -- (270:2cm) -- cycle;
\draw (0, 0.3) node {Hello};
\draw (0, -0.3) node {Goodbye};
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=black!40, draw = black!40, line width=2pt]
    (-2, -2.5) rectangle +(\textwidth, 4cm);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-3.8cm]
\draw (2, -0.3) node[draw, right, text
    width=\textwidth-4.5cm] {This is a test as you can see and we put more text to see what happens here and there.};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=\textwidth-4cm]
\draw[red, fill=white, rounded corners = 5pt, line width=10pt]
    (30:2cm) -- (150:2cm) -- (270:2cm) -- cycle;
\draw (0, 0.3) node {Hello};
\draw (0, -0.3) node {Goodbye};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd version:**

Although I'd prefer to do it with `nodes` and their `positioning` capabilities.

The sign is a `regular polygon` with 3 sides. `Hello` and `Goodbye` can be added to it with a `label=center:...`.

The `text` is just a regular node which can be placed `above/below right` or `above/below left` from the sign.

And the gray background can be drawn after both nodes. You have different options, thanks to `background` tikzlibrary: 
 - `show background rectangle` 
 - a filled rectangle on background layer 
 - filled `fitting` node (needs `fit` tikzlibrary) on background layer

Next code shows how I did it. Second picture changes `below left` by `below right`. That's all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=black!40, 
                                    inner frame sep=3pt},
                    show background rectangle]
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, line width=10pt, rounded corners,
      minimum size=3.6cm+\pgflinewidth, draw=red, fill=white, 
      shape border rotate=60, 
      label={[text width=1.5cm,align=center]center:{Hello\\Goodbye}}] 
      (sign) at (0,0){};

\node[below right=-2mm and 2cm of sign.center, 
      text width=\textwidth-4.5cm] (text) 
      {This is a test as you can see and we put more 
          text to see what happens here and there.};

\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=black!40, 
                                    inner frame sep=3pt},
                    show background rectangle]
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, line width=10pt, rounded corners,
      minimum size=3.6cm+\pgflinewidth, draw=red, fill=white, 
      shape border rotate=60, 
      label={[text width=1.5cm,align=center]center:{Hello\\Goodbye}}] 
      (sign) at (0,0){};

\node[below left=-2mm and 2cm of sign.center, 
      text width=\textwidth-4.5cm] (text) 
      {This is a test as you can see and we put more 
          text to see what happens here and there.};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]